# error installing body-parser v1.17.0

Tags: node.js, windows, express

i am trying to install body-parser using 
npm install body-parser --save
i got this error

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program       Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "body-parser"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! enoent getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! enoent getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Omowumi\nodefirstapp\npm-debug.log
```

kindly help
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not a node error but a DNS error.
try running using CMD: 'ping registry.npmjs.org' from the machine, should fail too. if so, set your DNS to google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)